# NMR Concept Help

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, ferromagnetism

I am trying to grasp the concept of Nuclear Magnetic Resonance machines that use permanent magnets. From what I understand you use a electromagnet to align the atoms with the field, turn off the field and allow the atoms to oscillate until they align with the permanent magnetic field and read the rf waves that are emitted. The part I am having trouble understanding is with a strong Halbach array (0.5T+) how powerful does the electromagnet need to be. Does it need to overpower the permanent magnets (higher tesla)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a chemists perspective, the magnetic field is used to increase the [Zeemann splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) of nuclei with a non-zero nuclear spin.  (For chemists, 1H, 13C, 15N, 19F, and 31P are the more often tracked ones; for physicians and their fMRI likely the 1H.)

The stronger the magnetic field, the larger the energy differences observable when exciting the nuclei with radio frequency (for 1H, 300 to 600 MHz is typical, about 1 GHz was already achieved).  The magnetic field however is kept very stable over time, and spatially homogeneous.

The larger FT-NMR spectrometer benefit from supra-conducting electromagnets, with typically field strengths of about 5 T.

Using permanent magnets has the benefit that you do not have to refill liquid nitrogen and liquid helium (the later often recycled), yet obviously do not offer the same field strengths.  In the 1990s, for example, I saw such a smaller spectrometer put under the writing desk of a TA, used to check *simple* products of an introductory lab class in organic chemistry.  With the increased sensitivity of electronic devices, and better permanent magnet materials / design allowing a better focus on the sample (sometimes just on some droplets) bench top spectrometers with permanent magnets enjoy a renaissance -- sometimes just as small as about a shoe-box with 1H resonances of about 60 MHz at field strength of about 1.4 T ([an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZQXiszWuuk)).  Even mobile devices like the [NMR mouse](http://www.nmr-mouse.de/), are now possible.

While I'm not affiliated with picoSpin, nor an other corporation distributing such spectrometers, I see that they are complementary to each other.  The small shoe-boxes (30 to 50 k$) do well again in lab classes (*vide supra*), some QC routine and for continuous flow analyses like in process control.  The more expensive measurement time of the high-field spectrometers may be then used to record data of less frequent nuclei, or to record data of experiments lasting hours.

Comment: Thanks for the informative comment. As for taking those atoms into a different energy state that is done with a electromagnet that is at 90 degrees to the permanent magnet, how strong do the electromagnets need to be in comparison to the permanent magnet?

Comment: @Goodwin The excitation of the nuclear spin is provided by the incident radio coil, operating almost at the Larmor precession frequency of the nuclei to be characterized.  Hence, for a given strength of magnetic field & isotope, the spectrometers possess different probe heads (as a side note, some experiments require more than one radio channel for NMR data acquisition).  The strength of the magnetic field influences the spread of the energy levels.  The large NMR spectrometers possess only an electromagnet (https://www.warlock.com.au/NMRdeconstruction300MHz.htm).

Comment: @Goodwin  And to my best knowledge (for the better I am not trying to move the screws, either), the modern bench top spectrometers operate with permanent magnets only; and house the advanced electronics in the same box, too.